# Is there a way to use Expression.In() in a case insensitive way?

Tags: c#, nhibernate, orm

I am using Expression.In() as a part of a criteria using NHibernate and for the life of me I can't find any way to make it ignore case.  Does anyone know how this can be done or am I going to have to do this a different way?

Not that it probably matters much but here is a sample of how I am using the Expression.In()

```
ICriteria criteria = Session.CreateCriteria(typeof (Result))
    .Add(Expression.In("targetName", {'target1', 'target2'}));
```

Comment: I am primarily using Sqlite and MySql.  (Through NHibernate of course)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think case handling differs for each db server. For example, by default mssql server is case-insensitive. So either check into that setting on your db or convert all strings to upper or lower before comparing.

```
.Add(Restrictions.In(
    Projections.SqlFunction("lower", NHibernateUtil.String, Projections.Property("targetName")), 
    new object[] {"target1", "target2"} ))
```